# SSRS report loads and never finishes loading

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report which was working correctly and is still working correctly for all other clients except for one. the report just keeps loading and loading. When I hardcode the date values, the report runs in 40-50 seconds. The query against their db takes 30-50 seconds. I created a new report and took off all filters except for the date ones and removed all grouping and limited the report to only show 2 rows per page. Even this basic altered version of the report does not run. I added the link to the internet for compatibility too and it still doesn't run .

Here is the additional information from the execution log
Processing takes: 1078112

Comment: Have you checked the server when the report is 'loading'. I have seen instances where the report has completed but the browser simply does not update. When I check the server, nothing is happening as all processing is complete. Often simply clearing the browsers cache fully resolved the issue.

Comment: Alan, I haven't checked it but if this was indeed the issue wouldn't the other reports also not run? The other intensive reports are running fine. Also if it was a browser cache issue why would the report run when I hard-code the date values.

Comment: Its not that  the reports didn't run, it was that even after the query had executed ok on the server, the report would still show 'loading'. Other users could run the same report with no issues. Clearing the cache resolved it. The parameters being hard coded would mean the bad cached copy would not be used (possibly). It might not be the problem but at least it's a quick test and you never know your luck!

Comment: Alan, I just cleared the cache but it is still not running. I ran it again with hard-coded values and it runs in 1 min.

Comment: I'm not sure what else to check other than runnign a trace and executing the report from a working and non-working PC to compare what is actually being executed. Once you have determined that the same query is being run, you can then compare the execution log times, the data retrieval tims should be very similar, if render time is longer, then that might point to a local resource issue on the pc

Comment: Alan, if it was a resource issue wouldn't the report still not run when I hardcode the values? I need the report to run for a month's of data and 1 minute is fine for that time frame when I hardcode the values.

Comment: finally got the report to run again. It was the issue of parameter sniffing from the date columns. I followed the solution below and then hid the original date parameters and gave them a default value of 1 in SSRS.